# Subtract a row from previous row which has value from previous group in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a pandas DataFrame in Python as Below:

```
   A   --  E    user
0  0   --  0   1
1  12  --  1   1
2  12  --  1   1
3  13  --  2   1
4  15  --  3   1
5  15  --  3   1
6  15  --  3   1
7  19  --  4   2
8  20  --  5   2
9  25  --  6   2
10 25  --  6   2
```

I want to subtract 1 row from the previous group/set of value(ie, it should not be 0) [groupby E] for each user

What I mean is to have a DataFrame as below:

```
   A            --  E   user
0  0            --  0   1
1  12           --  1   1
2  12           --  1   1
3  1(ie,13-12)  --  2   1
4  2 (  --   )  --  3   1
5  2            --  3   1
6  2            --  3   1
7  19           --  4   2 (should not change at user 2) 
8  1            --  5   2
9  5(ie,25-20)  --  6   2
10 5(ie,25-20)  --  6   2
```

Can You please help me..Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in `E` column are unique groups use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), replace mising values by original with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with mask for consecutive values (compared for not equal shifted values) and then forward filling missing values with `ffill` and last to integers:

```
df['A1'] = (df.groupby('user')['A'].diff()
              .fillna(df['A'])
              .where(df['E'].ne(df['E'].shift()))
              .ffill()
              .astype(int))
print (df)
     A  E  user  A1
0    0  0     1   0
1   12  1     1  12
2   12  1     1  12
3   13  2     1   1
4   15  3     1   2
5   15  3     1   2
6   15  3     1   2
7   19  4     2  19
8   20  5     2   1
9   25  6     2   5
10  25  6     2   5
```

Comment: @TimothyAlexJohn - Some problem?

Comment: I missed one more column which correctly explains my problem..can you check my update?  i am very sorry..I only came to know this when i applied it into my dataframe.

Comment: thanks!! I am checking the result..it takes a lot of time bcz it is a big dataframe..I will update when result comes right!!  Thanks For your great Help..

Comment: It worked fine!!  is there any way to give you a hundred upvotes...you Helped so much..ThankYou